# Question deleted because of "product recommendations". But this was the only way to answer the question

Tags: support

[My question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/213444/27264) was closed because of "product recommendations". The suggestion is "describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve".

I described my problem I tried to solve, and the only way to solve the problem is to suggest a product. And I had to do it myself, spending very much time. And I've not publicized a single product, I created a list of products that can solve the problem.

I think this is the famous exception that confirm the rule. It's a borderline case, and I ask that the question and answer will be undeleted and reopened, because IMHO they can be very useful to other people with my same problem.

Comment: Everybody thinks *they* are the exception.

Comment: @MechMK1 All that glitters isn't gold.

Comment: Aphorisms aside, the reason why product recommendations are off-topic is because they quickly become obsolete and they can't be formulated neutrally. Your question suffers from those exact two problems as well, so that's why the question was closed. Saying "It would be useful to other people" doesn't fix these points either.

Comment: Thanks @MechMK1, but the motivation of deleting was already explained to me by [schroeder](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder) and [Steffen Ullrich](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37315/steffen-ullrich)

Answer (score 6):

If a product/service is the only way to answer the question, then the question is not a good fit here.

Your question was

> "Where can I get such a certificate?"

And your answer was a list of CAs.

Is your list exhaustive? What if the list changes? What if more CA's offer that kind of cert? It's these questions that make the post off-topic because the list of potential vendors could be endless and the list could change from day to day.

It's just not a good fit for a Q&A site, and we have already explained this.

Comment: But this is a question. IMHO it's a legitimate question. And I can't rephrase it in any other better way. It's not possible that in a QA site a question _can't_ be published, because of it's nature.

My humble opinion is that the rule of not searching product recommendations is to stimulate people to do more generic and useful questions. But in this case the question can't be formulated in any other way and can't be answered in any other better way.

Comment: What if the list changes? Well, answers can be edited. I see a lot of time answers with broken links. We have to ban links because they can be broken?

If someone finds that a link does not work or the CA does not offer anymore that service, he can remove it. If someone else knows a not listed CA, he can add it. Really, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @MarcoSulla, answers _can_ be edited. They generally won't be edited, though, without good cause. Don't assume that any answer will be updated.  It may be a useful question for you at this point in time, but it's just not a good fit for a Q&A site. Someone shouldn't be the custodian of a topic that could change week from week on a site that only gives fake internet points, simply because they decided to give an answer.

Comment: @MarcoSulla I don't think you are getting the point. Some questions, which might, in general, be fine questions, are just not a good fit on a Q&A site. It's the ***fit*** that's the problem. I agree that there is no way for you to rephrase the question in a way that could fit here.

Comment: This is frustrating, you know? o__0